# HOW TO SOLVE SQFLITE CHECK ERROR IN FLUTTER?

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqflite

I am creating database in SQFLITE but I am checking if the user exists or not in the database but what happens is when I click on the button it does nothing I try Debugging the program what came to see when I click on the button it calls the method for method and then just close the method ignoring all the checks in it I have no Idea what to do

HERE IS THE METHOD FOR CHECKING

```
getallusers() {

//using delay method min 500s, because database takes time to initialize
Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 500), () async {
  userslist = await mydb.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
  print(userslist);
  userslist.forEach((element){
    print([element['email']]);
    if (email.text == element['email']) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text("USER ALREADY EXISTS")));
      // logn_in;
      // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      //     builder: (BuildContext Context) => const logn_in()));
    } else if (firstname.text.isEmpty &&
        lastname.text.isEmpty &&
        email.text.isEmpty &&
        pass.text.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text("PLEASE ENTER SOMETHING")));
    } else {
      mydb.db.rawQuery(
          "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,pass) VALUES(?,?,?,?);",
          [firstname.text, lastname.text, email.text, pass.text]);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("New User Added")));
      firstname.clear();
      lastname.clear();
      email.clear();
      pass.clear();
    }
  }
  );

  setState(() {});
});
```

}

I DONT KNOW WHATS WRONE WITH MY CODE OR PROGRAM PLEASE I NEED HELP CONTACT ME I'LL SEND YOU WHOLE CODE TO CHECK PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: In your code get any output from this print([element['email']]);

Comment: bro even if its wrong the loop should go to next statement and should atleast sow snackbar or insert or atleast should show error but its just does not response and when i debug it  the execution just goes to 2nd line and then just to end of method not response when click on the button dont know what to do can you check me code i can you whole code if u want just help

Comment: okay send your code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q4DbX6wMi64l2b1HMXZK0ZqbGU3H-NP2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: cmon man help me

Comment: I add another answer please check that will be work or not

Answer (score 0):

/// database helper class

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper.internal();

  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db!;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db!;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  Future<dynamic> initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "main.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserData(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT, avatar TEXT)");
  }

  Future<void> delete() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "FlutterDemo.db");
    await deleteDatabase(path);
  }
}
```

/// for save,get and delete data

```
class AppResDataBase {
  static DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();

  /// save data to local storage   ('UserData' TableName)
  static Future<int> saveData(ApiResData apiResDataList) async {
    var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("UserData", apiResDataList.toJson(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    log('dbClient response $res');
    return res;
  }

  /// get data from local storage
  static Future<List<ApiResData>> getData() async {
    var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM UserData');
    List<ApiResData> apiResDataList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      apiResDataList.add(ApiResData.fromJson(list[i]));
    }
    return apiResDataList;
  }

  /// delete data to local storage
  static Future<int> deleteData() async {
    var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
    int index = await dbClient.delete('UserData');
    return index;
  }
}
```

/// Insert, delete and get data like this way...

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    ApiResData data = ApiResData(
        id: 1,
        avatar: 'https://profilePictureUrl.com',
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'testData');
    await AppResDataBase.saveData(data);
  },
  child: Text('SaveData'),
),
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    List<ApiResData> dataList = await AppResDataBase.getData();
    print('dataList Length: ${dataList.length}');
  },
  child: Text('GetData'),
),
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await AppResDataBase.deleteData();
  },
  child: Text('DeleteData'),
),
```

/// Response model

```
class ApiResData {
  ApiResData({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.avatar,
  });

  ApiResData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;
  ApiResData copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? email,
    String? firstName,
    String? lastName,
    String? avatar,
  }) =>
      ApiResData(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        email: email ?? this.email,
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        avatar: avatar ?? this.avatar,
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['email'] = email;
    map['first_name'] = firstName;
    map['last_name'] = lastName;
    map['avatar'] = avatar;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify dbhelper.dart file as...

```
class MyDb {
  static final MyDb _instance = MyDb.internal();

  factory MyDb() => _instance;
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db!;
    _db = await open();
    return _db!;
  }

  MyDb.internal();

  Future open() async {
    var DatabasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(DatabasePath, "my_database");

    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
        id PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(255),
        lastname VARCHAR(255),
        email VARCHAR(255),
        password VARCHAR(255)
        );
        ''');
      print("TABLE CREATED");
    });
    return theDb;
  }
}
```

save data like this...

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  MyDb databaseHelper = MyDb();
                  Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
                    "firstname": 'testUser',
                    "lastname": "demo",
                    "email": "test@gmail.com",
                    "password": "test123",
                  };
                  var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
                  int res = await dbClient.insert("users", userData, conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
                },
                child: const Text("SaveData"),
              )
```

get data like...

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                MyDb databaseHelper = MyDb();
                  var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
                  List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM users');
                  log('dbClient response ${list.toString()}');
                },
                child: const Text("GetData"),
              )
```

Comment: bro its all wokring but the probelm is when i insert the data i want to check if the data already exists or not in database in sign up

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be works,this code checks the user exists in sqflite storage before saving the data.

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                MyDb databaseHelper = MyDb();
                Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
                  "id": '1',
                  "firstname": 'testUser',
                  "lastname": "demo",
                  "email": "test@gmail.com",
                  "password": "test123",
                };
                var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
                bool isUserExist = await checkUserExist(id: userData['id']);
                if (isUserExist) {
                  log('User already exist');
                } else {
                  int response = await dbClient.insert("users", userData);
                  log('response : $response');
                }
              },
              child: const Text("SaveData"),
            ),
```

/// this method is used to check is user is exist or not.(you can use either email or ID.)

```
Future<bool> checkUserExist({required String id}) async {
    MyDb databaseHelper = MyDb();
    var dbClient = await databaseHelper.db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM users');
    int index = list.indexWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
    if (index != -1) {
      log('User is exist');
      return true;
    } else {
      log('User not found!');
      return false;
    }
  }
```